# Can't connect flask sqlAlchemy to the mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql, alembic

I'm trying to connect my flask app with the MySQL database.
here's MySQL data

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| alchemy            |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

here's **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

here's config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'test-key-motherfucker'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3360/alchemy'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

and models.py

```
from app import db

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Test {}>'.format(self.name)
```

when I try to init db with

```
flask db init
flask db upgrade
```

I receive

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql
```

I tried to use pymysql
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://rootl@127.0.0.1:3360/alchemy'

how to connect mysql with sqlalchemy?

Comment: There is a typo here in port number: 
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3360/alchemy'`
it should be 3306

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the right why to connect to mysql database is

```
mysql://username:password@server/db
```

try this first

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/alchemy'
```

if it did not work try this

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/alchemy'
```

if it did not work try this

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/alchemy
```

i am sorry for putting many options but i hope one of them work :)

if none worked then the problem not the connection with the database